# Equations over fields

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ be distinct elements of a given field $F$ such that for any $k$, $\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^k = 0$. I want to show that all $x_i$'s are zero.

Comment: This is almost self-contradictory since $x_1,\dots,x_n$ being distinct and $\forall i,x_i=0$ are not compatible statements...

Comment: The result is false without "distinct" since in characteristic $p$ you could take $n = p$ and each $x_i = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Not a complete answer. In characteristic zero we can do the following. The claim is clear when $n = 1$; we will show that any counterexample to the claim gives rise to a counterexample with smaller $n$.

The condition forces any symmetric polynomial in the $x_i$ to vanish. To see this, note that
$$
0 = (x_1 + \ldots + x_n)^k
$$
for any $k$. (See the "properties" section of this page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial).

In particular,
$$
x_1x_2\ldots x_n = 0
$$
so one of the $x_i$ must be zero.

(If I'm not mistaken we don't need $F$ to be a field; the argument is true in any $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra which is a domain.)

Comment: We can also do this in finite characteristic $p$ so long as $n<p$.

Comment: Couldn't this argument work given characteristic $p$ and $n\not\equiv 0\pmod p$?

Comment: I think we're even ok if $n \geq p$, the point is, we just need to find SOME term which is forced to vanish and whose binomial coefficient isn't divisible by $p$. We don't care if say it looks like $x_1x_2^3\ldots x_n^{2}$, just so long as it is a monomial. So we can just pick a $k$ such that the next to last binomial coefficient isn't divisible by $p$.

Comment: We won't be able to do that when $p|n$, though, since it's not true!

Comment: yes, good point. we have to use the "distinct" hypothesis somewhere. ignore my last comment.